# What is the "status" in the autoscaler yaml in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-pipelines-yaml, horizontalpodautoscaler

I am trying to understand the k8s pod autoscaler and have the following question. Even the k8s documentation does not seem to talk about it.

[k8s pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

In the below yaml what is the "status" node for? Any pointers to the documentation will be of great help.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: php-apache
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: packets-per-second
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 1k
  - type: Object
    object:
      metric:
        name: requests-per-second
      describedObject:
        apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
        kind: Ingress
        name: main-route
      target:
        type: Value
        value: 10k
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  lastScaleTime: <some-time>
  currentReplicas: 1
  desiredReplicas: 1
  currentMetrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
    current:
      averageUtilization: 0
      averageValue: 0
  - type: Object
    object:
      metric:
        name: requests-per-second
      describedObject:
        apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
        kind: Ingress
        name: main-route
      current:
        value: 10k
```

Answer (score 1):

`status` describes the current state of the object, supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system and its components. The master node (control plane) continually and actively manages every object's actual state to match the desired state you supplied.

[Kubernetes status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#object-spec-and-status)

Comment: If k8s updates it, is it optional in the yaml then? I still don't get it as to why I should have it in the yaml if the master node manages it ? Because I don't see this "status" in any other yaml like "Deployment", "ReplicaSet" etc.

Comment: When creating or updating a manifest, you do not specify the ```status``` inside yaml.